# Removing capital letters from a python string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to figure out how to remove capital letters from a string using Python but without the `for` loop.

I’m trying to do this while traversing a list using a `while` loop.

So how can I remove the capital letters in a provided string?

Comment: Removing, as in remove it from the string completely or substitute them with lowercase letters?

Comment: Why use a while loop?

Comment: Remove completely

Comment: You can turn any for loop into a while loop by just manually creating an iterator and nexting it each time the loop, or manually creating an int for indexing and incrementing it by 1 each time through the loop. I have no idea why you’d want to do that, but if your requirement is “use a while loop” for some reason, that’s the obvious way to meet that requirement.

Comment: Also are you really traversing a *list* or are you traversing a *string*?

Comment: Using a while loop because the strings are in a list

Comment: Yes, my requirement is to use a list just like abarnert stated, but I can’t figure out how to remove the capital letters from the string

Comment: Why not just use a comprehension like `[''.join(c for c in s if not c.isupper()) for s in strings]`? Even if you can't use a list comprehension, the expression in that comprehension shows one way to remove upper case letters from a string.

Comment: Can’t use the for command

Comment: I really wish teachers would come up with an assignment where a while loop is the obvious right answer, instead of giving an assignment where a for loop is much better and then artificially telling people to do it with a while. If they’re trying to teach/test how to transform one into the other, then fine, but usually they’re just teaching/testing how to use a while loop in the first place, and a problem like this just teaches people that while loops are stupid and programming is tedious.

Comment: Yea I’m in an intro class and we haven’t learned for loops.

Comment: Well then, I wish teachers would teach for loops first. I understand they learned in either C or Lisp, where the equivalent of a for loop is a lot more complicated than a while loop, so their teacher started with while. But they’re teaching Python, not C, and the first problem they come up with is “loop over each string in this list”, they should teach the easy way to do it first.

Answer (score 6):

Strings are immutable, so you can’t literally remove characters from them, but you can create a new string that skips over those characters.

The simplest way is:

```
s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if not ch.isupper())
```

If you want to do this without `for` for some reason (like an assignment requirement), we can write this out as an explicit loop, and then convert it to a `while`. So:

```
result = []
for ch in s:
    if not ch.isupper(): result.append(ch)
s = ''.join(result)
```

To change the loop, we have to manually setup and next the iterator, but it may be easier to understand with just a plain int as an index instead of an iterator:

```
result = []
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    ch = s[i]
    if not ch.isupper(): result.append(ch)
    i += 1
s = ''.join(result)
```

Of course this is more verbose, slightly less efficient, and easier to get wrong, but otherwise it’s basically equivalent, and it meets your strange requirements.

In real life, there might be better ways to do this—e.g., `str.translate` with a map from all caps to None should be pretty fast if you only care about ASCII caps—but I assume your teacher doesn’t want you thinking in those directions, they want you thinking about the loops explicitly. (Of course there is a loop in `str.translate`, or `re.sub`, etc., that loop is just hidden under the covers where you don’t see it.)

If you need to do this to multiple strings in a list, you’d wrap it up in a function, and apply it to each string in the list, using a comprehension—or you can write it out as a loop statement, and convert it to a `while` loop, if you prefer, in exactly the same way. For example:

```
def remove_caps(s):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        ch = s[i]
        if not ch.isupper(): result.append(ch)
        i += 1
    return ''.join(result)

strings = ['aBC', 'Abc', 'abc', '']
new_strings = []
i = 0
while i < len(strings):
    new_strings.append(remove_caps(strings[i]))
    i += 1
```

Comment: More like OP's teacher's strange requirements... ;)

Comment: @uwain12345 Well, yeah, I suppose the OP’s only real requirement is “I want to meet my teacher’s strange requirements so I pass the assignment”. But I think it’s worth pointing out why, outside this assignment, you would actually want to use a `while` here.

Comment: I'd write `s = ''.join([ch for ch in s if not ch.isupper()])` or `s = ''.join(filter(str.isupper,s))`. Both are faster than a gencomp passed to `str.join`. BTW your quotes are _really_ strange in your post.

Comment: Is there no way to do this by splitting/joining/slicing?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, passing an iterator to str.join means it just makes a list out of them in CPython. But that’s a small constant performance difference that isn’t likely to matter. Plus, optimizing for it relies on knowing the internals of (or at least testing the hell out of) one specific language implementation. When it isn’t relevant, just write the one that’s clearest. I think it’s clearer with a genexpr here because as far as behavior is concerned, we don’t care what kind of iterable we’re building; if we use [] we’re signaling that the performance mattered here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre As for the quotes—I’ll try to re-edit once I get to a real computer. Thanks.

Comment: don't bother for the quotes.

Comment: @Wisestudents Sure. For example, you could loop over every capital letter in the relevant charset, and do `s = ‘’.join(s.split(letter))` for each one. If you’re willing to learn regular expressions, you can turn that into a single `re.split` on a character class—but then you could just `re.sub` instead of splitting and rejoining. There’s usually lots of ways to solve a problem, but most of them just add complexity (or performance costs or missing edge cases) without buying you anything; that’s what TOOWTDI is about.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for fixing it. I still can’t get used to tablets after all these years. When I were a lad, a computer took up a whole room, and you had to burn a month’s supply of peat moss just to add two numbers, and we liked it!

Comment: No sweat. don't try to write an answer using MS-Word either :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre MS Word? Nah. If an answer is too complicated to edit in-place I use emacs markdown-mode (configured for SO markdown) of course. But sadly, I don’t have that on my phone or tablet. And the iOS virtual keyboard doesn’t have a meta key, for some reason I can’t comprehend. :)

Comment: back on topic: `while i < len(s):
        if not ch.isupper(): result.append(ch)` doesn't work `ch` isn't defined

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well, I did say it was "easier to get wrong", didn't I? :) Fixed.

Comment: not in all snippets :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Now? (If I've still screwed it up, I'm going to go in and write the damn `__iter__`/ `__next__` version…)

Comment: nah it's all good now (note that there were if and is typos, some other user fixed that as well).

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here:

1) If you simply want to convert all upper-case letters to lower-case, then `.lower()` is the simplest approach.

```
s = 'ThiS iS A PyTHon StrinG witH SomE CAPitaL LettErs'
```

Gives:

```
this is a python string with some capital letters
```

2) If you want to completely remove them, then `re.sub()` is a simple approach.

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'[A-Z]', '', s))
```

Gives:

```
hi i  yon trin wit om ita ettrs
```

3)

For a list of strings, you could use a list comprehension:

```
#Option1
[i.lower() for i in s])

#Option2
import re

[re.sub(r'[A-Z]', '', i) for i in s])

#Option3 (as mentioned by @JohnColeman)
[''.join([j for j in i if not j.isupper()]) for i in s]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this by slicing or joining the string? I’m not permitted to use the commands provided above

Comment: check John Coleman comment/answer, then

Comment: I think a student who hasn’t learned for loops yet isn’t going to be able to understand any of these but the first—but it’s very cool to show them anyway, and maybe make them (or other students with the same problem) curious enough to learn more than the class syllabus. Especially for a student already asking “Isn’t there a better way?” and trying to figure it out.