# Python - Finding all uppercase letters in string

Tags: python

I'm really a beginner with Python and I'm trying to modify codes that I have seen in lessons. I have tried the find all uppercase letters in string. But the problem is it only returns one uppercase letter in string even if there are more than one.

```
def finding_uppercase_iterative(string_input):
    for i in range(len(string_input)):
        if string_input[i].isupper:
            return string_input[i]
    return "No uppercases found"
```

How should I modify this code to give me all uppercase letters in given string. If someone can explain me with the logic behind I would be glad.

Thank you!

Edit 1: Thank to S3DEV I have mistyped the binary search algorithm.

Comment: at the moment, you are "returning" the first found. In theory, you probably want to test each letter and append the uppercase ones to a list

Comment: May I just clarify that the posted code is *not* a [binary search algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: You are right. Thank you for correction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fixed code written out with a lot of detail to each step. There are some other answers with more complicated/'pythonic' ways to do the same thing.

```py
def finding_uppercase_iterative(string_input):
    uppercase = []
    
    for i in range(len(string_input)):
        if string_input[i].isupper():
            uppercase.append(string_input[i])
    
    if(len(uppercase) > 0):
        return "".join(uppercase)
    else:
        return "No uppercases found"

# Try the function
test_string = input("Enter a string to get the uppercase letters from: ")
uppercase_letters = finding_uppercase_iterative(test_string)
print(uppercase_letters)
```

Here's the explanation:

1. create a function that takes `string_input` as a parameter
2. create an empty list called `uppercase`
3. loop through every character in `string_input`
4. [in the loop] if it is an uppercase letter, add it to the `uppercase` list
5. [out of the loop] if the length of the `uppercase` list is more than 0
6. [in the `if`] return the list characters all joined together with nothing as the separator (`""`)
7. [in the `else`] otherwise, return "No uppercases found"
8. [out of the function] get a `test_string` and store it in a variable
9. get the `uppercase_letters` from `test_string`
10. `print` the `uppercase_letters` to the user

There are shorter (and more complex) ways to do this, but this is just a way that is easier for beginners to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I got the idea. I will try to use this form with different examples! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for only small changes that make your code work, one way is to use a generator function, using the `yield` keyword:

```
def finding_uppercase_iterative(string_input):
    for i in range(len(string_input)):
        if string_input[i].isupper():
            yield string_input[i]


print(list(finding_uppercase_iterative('test THINGy')))
```

If you just print `finding_uppercase_iterative('test THINGy')`, it shows a generator object, so you need to convert it to a list in order to view the results.

For more about generators, see here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: Hello Oli, thank you for your answer. Instead of using built-in functions I m trying to figure out the problem by coding to understand better programming. :)

Comment: @BugraYildirim: this answer uses [generators](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/), a slightly more advanced feature.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like this would work:

```
s = "My Word"
s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch.isupper())
return(s)
```

Inverse idea behind other StackOverflow question: [Removing capital letters from a python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281051/removing-capital-letters-from-a-python-string)

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement in a function will stop the function from executing. When it finds an uppercase letter, it will see the return statement and stop.

One way to do this is to append letters to list and return them at the end:

```
def finding_uppercase_iterative(string_input):
    letters = []
    for i in range(len(string_input)):
        if string_input[i].isupper():
             letters.append(string_input[i])
    if letters:
       return letters
    return "No uppercases found"
```

Comment: Hello Mohammad, it works :) But i have a question, why did you add if letters: return letters ?  I would like to know the reason to understand better. Thanks

Comment: `if letters` checks if the `letters` variable is not empty. if its empty, the first return will not pass. Instead it will give: "No uppercases found". This is the same as writing `if letters != []`

Comment: @BugraYildirim: I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68717721/14469685) with a full explanation, if you want to see that too.